# Direct and reverse waves

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation

let's consider a generic wave that propagates in space and time, expressed in frequency domain:

$$V(x)=A\cdot e^{-kx} + B\cdot e^{kx}$$

It may represent the voltage along a transmission line, or any physical quantity that appears in a second order differential equation that satisfies the oscillation conditions.

In time - domain it becomes something like that:

$$V(x)=A\cdot cos(-kx+\omega t) + B\cdot cos(kx+\omega t)$$

The first term is usually called **direct or incident wave**, while the second one is called **reverse or reflected wave**. They are two waves that moves in space and time, and precisely the first one moves towards x axis, while the second one moves in the opposite direction to the x axis.

My question is about this last statement: **why are the term with "-kx" the direct wave and the term  with "kx" the reverse wave?**

I tried to answer my question by using the concept of phase velocity. The phase velocity of a wave is defined as the velocity an observer should have in order not to see any difference of phase, i.e. such that:

$$d\cdot (-kx+\omega t) = 0$$ for the first term;

$$d\cdot (kx+\omega t) = 0$$ for the second term;

*So we get:*

$$-kdx + \omega dt = 0$$ for the first term;

$$kdx + \omega dt = 0$$ for the second term;

*and finally:*

$$v_{1} = dx/dt = \omega/k$$ for the first term;

$$v_{2} = dx/dt = - \omega/k$$ for the second term;

So the phase velocity of the first term is positive (so, towards x axis), while that of the second term is negative (so, opposite to x axis).

What does not convince me of this explanation is the fact that as far as I know the phase velocity does not represent the propagation velocity of the wavefront, but is simply the velocity corresponding to a zero phase difference. And thanks to the fact that it is not a propagation speed, it follows that it can be even greater than the speed of light (it is a known result of the analysis of waveguides, for instance).

Answer (score 7):

I believe you should plot these two waves starting with $t=0$ and then slowly increasing the time. [image]

The red is the incident wave, which travels into the positive $x$-direction. It is reflected at $x=1.2 \lambda$. The green wave is the reflected wave. Thus it travels into the negative $x$-direction. The blue wave is the superposition of these two waves.

Comment: Can you please tell me what program did you use yo make this animation?

Comment: I used R in combination with the packages ggplot2 and gganimate. However, this is a standard feature in almost all math programs, e.g. matlab, mathematica, python etc. Alternatively, you could probably generate "animated GIFs" using an external program as well.

Answer (score 2):

I see nothing wrong with your demonstration. For a monochromatic wave in an isotropic medium I think a wavefront may always indifferently by defined as a locus of constant phase or constant amplitude. Things only become more complicated with a propagating pulse (wave paket) in a dispersive medium and/or in a anisotropic medium. Anyway, the only other alternative I know is a classical (and very related) reasoning that you may already know:

Suppose you freeze the wave at an instant $t_{0}$ and measure the phase of the vibration $\psi$ at a particular location $x_{0}$. If you now let the wave run again for a short $\Delta t < 2\pi/ \omega$ and freeze the wave again at $t_{0}+\Delta t$. Where in the nearest neighborhood of $x_{0}$ will you find the same phase $\psi$?

Case 1 : $\psi=\omega t_{0} -kx_{0}$
Solving for $x$ such that $\omega (t_{0}+\Delta t)-kx = \psi $, yields  $x=x_{0}+v_{\psi}\Delta t$, with $v_{\psi}=\frac{\omega}{k}$

Case 2 : $\psi=\omega t_{0}+kx_{0}$
Solving for $x$ such that $\omega (t_{0}+\Delta t)+kx = \psi $, yields  $x=x_{0}-v_{\psi}\Delta t$.

Conclusion: In case 1 the wave propagates in the +$x$ direction, in case 2, the wave propagates in $-x$ direction.

Answer (score 0):

I think your concern is "because the negative sign applies to the *spatial* bit within the cosine and *not* to the time part, then how can it be that such becomes a *time* reversal (i.e. backward propagation)?"

This is simple. Note that $\cos$ is an even function.

$$\begin{align}
u_\mathrm{dir}(x, t) &:= A \cos(-kx + \omega t)\\
&= A \cos(-[-kx + \omega t])\\
&= A \cos(kx - \omega t)\end{align}$$

Thus, it is quite evident now that the "reflected wave"

$$u_\mathrm{ref}(x, t) := A \cos(kx + \omega t)$$

is the time reversal of the "direct wave", i.e.

$$u_\mathrm{ref}(x, t) = u_\mathrm{dir}(x, -t)$$

(ignoring the amplitude difference).

viz. it is travelling the other way. As for why we call the negative one reverse instead of calling the positive one - it is because there is a tendency to imagine the wave travelling toward the right. The term with negative $kx$ (or negative $\omega t$) term travels to the right.